# Match everything except certain cards

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My test string: `G4 G4 G7 G9 G9 R3 B4 RD2 R3 YD2 R4 R5 RR W BDT Y0 YS G8 WDF`

I've currently this expression `[^GWDF][0-9DTSRF]+`

 It matches everything beside the cards which start with `G` and it also doesn't match `WDF` and `W`.

https://regex101.com/r/cE9kY5/3

How can I make it so, that it also shouldn't match any card containing a `4` in it?

So it shouldn't match anything starting with a `G`, also it shouldn't match any card with a number `4` in it, and it shoudn't match `W` and `WDF`.

It should only match the following from the test string:

`R3 RD2 R3 YD2 R5 RR BDT Y0 YS`

Comment: Like this: [`[^GWDF](?!.?4)[0-9DTSRF]+`](https://regex101.com/r/pW1fC5/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the following regex:

```
[^\sGWDF](?!.?4)[0-9DTSRF]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW1fC5/2)

If you  need to match spaces, remove the `\s` from the expression.

The change I made is adding `(?!.?4)` negative look-ahead that fails the match if the next or the following character after the next character is `4`.